# Batch takes a part from the file name and create a folders with this part

Tags: c#, batch-file, vb6, powershell-3.0, jobs

I have files with names like this:

```
414_gtmlk_videos_Mas_147852_hty1147.xls
414_gtmlk_videos_Mas_P147852_hty1147.txt
```

I want to creat a job to check the filenames and take the part after `Mas` in the file name (147852-P147852) 
and create a folders with this part name (the folder name should be: 147852-P147852).
And finally move each file to his folder.

Comment: So it doesn't matter what's used such as batch script, powershell, C#, or VB? Also, the .xls and the .txt are both part of the same one txt file name, correct? Can you confirm that the first `147852` part of the file name will always be identical numbers in the part toward the end that always starts with a `P` but those numbers will always match? Will the number of underbars before the first number always be in the same as as well?

Comment: I don't see a question nor any code to help you with.

Comment: This is tagged with C#, VB6, Powershell.... what language are you really trying to use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some C# code below.  The first part does the following:

- Gets paths
- Get names of file
- Modify full paths to get "147852" part, between __Mas_ and last _

  ```
      string pathToGetFile = @"C:\\";
      string[] filePaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(pathToGetFile +@"\\", "*_Mas_*");
      string[] fullName = new string[filePaths.Length]; 

      for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
      {
          fullName[i] = filePaths[i].Substring(filePaths[i].LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

          filePaths[i] = filePaths[i].Substring(filePaths[i].LastIndexOf("_Mas_") + 5);
          int l = filePaths[i].IndexOf("_"); 
          filePaths[i] = filePaths[i].Substring(0, l);
  ```

Now you can create folders with yours names
filePaths is now like that:  147852, P147852

```
            if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\" + filePaths[i]))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\" + filePaths[i]);

        }
```

Now just move files to new directories

```
        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
        {
            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathToGetFile, fullName[i]);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"C:\" + filePaths[i], @"C:\" + filePaths[i] + "\\" + fullName[i]);

            File.Copy(sourceFile,destFile,true);
        }
```

Now, what happens

Files:

- C:\414_gtmlk_videos_Mas_147852_hty1147.xls
- C:\414_gtmlk_videos_Mas_P147852_hty1147.txt

They will be copied according to the:

- C:\147852\
- C:\P147852\

Comment: Upload the results in some accessible web location, kindly don't paste the links of files from your own hard-disk.

Comment: @Talha: The results are not the files but the file names!!

Comment: You're right, I called it wrong. I just wanted to illustrate what happens with the files.

Comment: thx a lot for you help
but i get an error in this parts:
 if (!Directory.Exists
 the error in !Directory
and the other one is in 
File.Copy

Comment: Can You send me text of this error? Maybe just something is wrong with path.
PS: Did you imported the library "using System.IO;" ?

Answer (score 3):

> **Batch takes a part from the file name and create a folders with this part i have files with names like this:
>   414_gtmlk_videos_Mas_147852_hty1147.xls
>   414_gtmlk_videos_Mas_P147852_hty1147.txt (the folder name will be
>   here:147852-P147852)**

Here's a way to do this with a Batch Script since you have this tagged as a `batch-file` in your question. Just set your source directory accordingly and the rest should just work based on the detail you provided and my understanding.

I used a simple batch [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop incorporating [MD](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html) with [IF](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) conditions. I used the underbar characters as the delimiter and set the token to 5 to make this work.

```
@ECHO ON

SET Src=C:\Folder\Path
FOR /F "TOKENS=5 DELIMS=_" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%Src%\*.txt"') DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%Src%\%%~F-P%%~F" MD "%Src%\%%~F-P%%~F"
    IF EXIST "%Src%\*%%~F*P%%~F*.txt" MOVE /Y "%Src%\*%%~F*P%%~F*.txt" "%Src%\%%~F-P%%~F"
)
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [IF](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [MD](http://ss64.com/nt/md.html)
- `FOR /?`

  ```
  delims=xxx      - specifies a delimiter set.  This replaces the
                    default delimiter set of space and tab.

  tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
                    be passed to the for body for each iteration.
                    This will cause additional variable names to
                    be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
                    specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
                    the last character in the tokens= string is an
                    asterisk, then an additional variable is
                    allocated and receives the remaining text on
                    the line after the last token parsed.
  ```

Comment: THX dear
but here also i have a problem with the position of the keyword 'MAS'
for example if other file name was  videos_Mas_147852_hty1147.xls 
in this case nothing will happen
the other quastion is : where i can change the keyword?i mean if i want to apply this batch with other keyword'ex:top' where i can change it?
thx

Comment: @hamsmm You should open a new question and add the additional question since this is different than you originally asked. I'm also confused if your example file name is [ONE file](https://i.imgur.com/RO2e9wo.png) or [TWO files](https://i.imgur.com/Wpoipsp.png)? Please confirm and I may be able to help further. Otherwise open a new question if you could for the changed criteria.

Comment: the problem was i forgot to include System.io library
it is working now thx for all